# Flask Sqlalchmey migration for unique not working

Tags: python, flask-migrate

I added some contraint to a column like this:

```
column_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
```

After doing this change I do the following:

```
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

I get an error that says that ALTER operation is not supported. I had the same problem before where I had to change the schema of the database. The DB changed successfully, but the head of the versions was not updated. That's why I simply did:

```
flask db stamp head
```

And the problem got solved.

But this is not the same problem. I just simply need that `column_name` to be unique, so I cannot see (at least in VS Code) if now this column is unique. However, if I do this two times:

```
c = Mymodel(column_name="hello")
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

I don't get an error. I would like to get an error that I cannot put the same thing in this column.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: @SuperShoot SQLite. I solved the problem by deleting it and creating it again.